# PHP server time-based instruction

Tags: php, sql, time

Im a seasoned dev that just wants to know if PHP is capable of setting variables at certain times of the day. For instance, I have a video of the day widget which I can manage on my own by changing the `WHERE id='$x`', but I'd like $x to $x to be randomized like executing `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1.` The issue with `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT` is that it changes every page load when I'd just want the `'$x' from WHERE id='$x'` to be changed at midnight every day.

So does PHP allow time-based executions, or is that considered a cron job? Please note I have no idea im just guessing terms.

Comment: have you considered letting a cron job trigger a php script?

Comment: could also do it from the sql

Comment: Personally I'd go with random limitations ie set the day into "times of day" ie: morning lunch afternoon evening then set flags against groups of videos in your db so they fall into one or many of the above time slots then do a rand pull from all videos where time slot matches the current time slot were in which can easily be defined via a switch case date now is between 0900-11:59 ie: morning slot.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side script executed by client. If you want it to do specific actions outside normal browsing, you need to set ap a cron job.

Comment: Ok. I figuredd; now time for me to research CRON examples and tutorials.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/ There isn't really much to research.

Comment: Yes that is the only reliable thing to do. You might have trigger clients your own scheduling but that will add to client request execution and your scheduler will not work while no clients connect. If you are using cron or similar you might want to check out PHP CLI.

Comment: So basically the best way to go about setting a random video of the day at 12AM is by setting a cron job?

Comment: Yes, the best way is to set up a cronjob, that will change the db entry of the id of a video to display on your website at a certain time of the day.

Comment: the crontab line of code is executable from shell access rite?

Answer (score 0):

If you're computing a "video of the day" link in response to a client request, I'd say go for a `rand()` call to determine `$x`, but seed the number generator with a value that depends only on the day:

```
<?php
srand(date('Ymd'));
$videoId = rand(0, 100);// change to whatever your maximum video id is
```

No need for an extra cron job and you don't need to store the value or modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

hi dear you can use php sever feature 'CRON JOB' this feature throw you can set according time execution of PHP script and update your web or application.

So First of all crate php script and set on SERVER file link and setting as time.

you can read this link and set file link on server.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml